# Does TRIM instantly deletes files deleted in on SSD?

Tags: windows, ssd, data-recovery, trim

If i deleted something from recycle bin, is it instantly gone when i have TRIM enabled? I deleted a file and i’d like to get it back but i don’t know if it’s even worth to try.

Answer (score 8):

**You will probably not be able to retrieve your data.**

SSD TRIM instructs the SSD to wipe the actual blocks where data was situated on a delete command (instead of just marking them as empty). As such, your data is very likely permanently gone.

It doesn’t cost to try, of course, but the answer is likely no.

Comment: It is also entirely possible that the SSD controller will simply return a block full of zeroes or ones on a TRIM'ed block. Far faster to give null data when you've already been told the block is garbage...

Comment: I don't know about Linux, but macOS only TRIMs upon startup and Windows has its own schedule. I don't believe it's usual thing to send TRIM commands immediately after a file is deleted.

Comment: @At0mic AFAIK, Windows TRIMs both on a schedule and on-demand as files are deleted.

Comment: @At0mic, it depends on the behaviour of the flash disk controller -- some perform erases synchronously and all other commands must wait until that is complete, while others can make a note in the log that the block has been freed, and will perform the actual erase at a moment when the command queue has been empty for a while, or only contains commands for another bank.

Comment: TRIM actually erases now? The security perspective I was taught was TRIM tells the controller to not bother, but it's not a reliable erase if you dismantle the disk.

Comment: @Joshua: I think you meant "to not bother *copying a page when recycling the containing block*, which would be the way I understand the behavior.

Comment: @supercat: I actually meant bother _preserving the information_ but to each his own.

Comment: @Joshua no promises. It may not (it probably doesn't) but in any case there's no likely way to get the data back short of destructive measures. Your perspective is pretty much right. But an eager erase now might be better for performance than a lazy erase when a write comes in, so it's not out of the question.

Comment: @Joshua, it's not reliable at all, as erase groups tend to be larger than single blocks. The controller will track usage of groups, and move the remaining data out when a group drops below a threshold, then the group can be erased (and usually is soon). Deleting a large file that was written in one go is likely to invalidate entire groups at once, as the blocks were allocated together.

Comment: @Joshua: The key point is not to bother *making any particular effort to preserve the information* [such as copying it out of blocks that are going to be recycled].  If a block has one page which has been trimmed, and the remainder of the block contains useful data, reclaiming storage from the trimmed page would require copying all of the valid data from that block to some other blank space.  Doing so purely for purposes of making one more blank page immediately available would generally not be worthwhile, but implementations may arbitrarily decide to do so anyway for a variety of reasons.